# Url error in bibliography

Tags: urls

How do I get rid of this error in my references.bib file?

```
<inserted text> 
                $
l.64 ...45dece/GLEN_2019-Q4_ProductionReport.pdf}}
                                                  .
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> \egroup
```

I just want the link to the website in the references, I don't want to post math!

Comment: If you're loading the `hyperref` package try putting the url inside a `\url{...}` command. If that doesn't solve your problem, post a minimal working example showing what the bib entry looks like, what bibliography packages you're using, and so on, making it clear whether you're using bibtex or biblatex, etc.

Comment: Without doing something special (like using `\url{...}`), TeX thinks that `_` means you want a subscript `2` and subscript `P` in math.  It therefore decides that you left out a begin-math symbol, and that the `}` means you forgot to end the math that you forgot to begin.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE., @Oskar Nicholson. Check what is your `\bibliographystyle` and if (and how) it accepts `url` inputs. If it does, probably you will have to use a package that know how to handle it such as `hyperref`, `url`, `xurl`, etc. Furthermore, I suggest reading about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)s and how to communicate here the issues your are facing. Without precise information from you, the best we can do is only guess what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Whether URL strings occur in bibliographies or elsewhere in a document, they should always be encased in `\url{...}` directives, for two separate reasons:

1. URL strings may contain TeX-special characters, such as `_` (as is the case in your document), `#`, and `&`. Encasing all URL strings in `\url{...}` wrappers serves to "shield" any TeX-special characters from being interpreted in, well, special ways. For instance, the `_` (underscore) character serves to initiate subscript mode, but as such it is valid only in math mode. Clearly, that's not the intended meaning if the character is used in a URL string.
2. URL strings are frequently long and unwieldy. This can easily result in overfull lines, as TeX's line-breaking algorithm determines (correctly!) that the components of URL strings are not ordinary "words" and hence that its hyphenation rules aren't applicable. This, in turn, is the motivation for the frequently-found recommendation to load the [xurl](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xurl) package, as it allows URL strings that are encased in `\url` wrappers to be line-broken *anywhere*.

   Loading the `xurl` package (or the older `url` package) provides a further benefit: You can choose which font family should be used to display URL strings. The package's `\urlstyle` command lets select from among `tt` (teletype -- the default), `rm` (roman -- the default or main text font), `sf` (sans-serif), and `same` (the *current* text font).